# Proxmox: How to replicate runnable VMs

Tags: cluster, replication, synchronization, proxmox

I am quite new to Proxmox 6.0 and just started to learn clustering.
I am running a test environment with an HP Proliant and an IBM rackserver (both have just one fat partition and the dataformat is zfs). We are just going to use this virtualisation internally, so we are planning to do the following:

The HP Proliant will run permanently and the IBM will start from time to time to get the VMs from the HP replicated. This saves energy (since HA Cluster is not necessary for us) and it works fine so far.

But I do not understand, how I could start the replicated VMs on the IBM in case the HP is completely dead. They do not appear in the GUI (just on the dead node) and if I try to start them, it says, that it can not connect to host.

Thank you for your answer!